# load missing library from ~/ without root or symlinks on shared hosting?

Tags: root, php, shared-library

So I have a library file that is used by a php module, both of which reside in my home dir on my shared hosted cpanel account.

Problem is this library depends on libcrypto.so.6 and libssl.so.6 files or symlinks by that name to whatever is the current version you have. (These particular versions do not exist on centos anymore)

Is there any way i get around this ? maybe change the referenced filenames in the library, or make a wrapper for the library ? or

Comment: Have you tried making the symlinks with appropriate names in a directory and pointing to that with the env. var. LD_LIBRARY_PATH ?

Comment: thanks @Anthon, i was thinking about this as an option too, but i cannot create symlinks, but i could put actual library, say in the home dir, but how to make LD_LIBRARY_PATH look there when that library is loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the libraries in `~/mylib` and set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to search there:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/mylib
```

You can put that line in your `~/.bashrc` if you want it to be available more permanently.

Comment: I understand what you are suggesting, but will ~/.bashrc be loaded in the context that i need it? As im not running a bash script; webpay_php.so is loaded as a php extension, which loads libwebpayclient.so ( via dlopen() ) which is linked to the missing libcrypto.so.6 and libssl.so.6 libs.

Comment: @HaydenThring Assuming your login shell is bash, it will be loaded and available for the next time you login. That is why you would put it there.

Comment: but I am not logging in, it is the webserver that runs php while serving the webpage ?

Comment: If your webserver is running via systemd, then you can add `ENVIRONMENT=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/mylib` to your service file which triggers your php instance.

Comment: Whatever is loading webpay_php.so is being executed by something.  It could be your desktop environment, systemd, bash.  Just let us know what the parent process is of the process which loaded webpay_php.so.